# Valid string for UTCTIMESTAMP

Tags: quickfix

The quifix engine rejects the message saying

Reject Message

```
58=Incorrect data format for value 371=5017 372=8
```

Original message (ExecutionReport), contains the tag

```
5017=-3:00:00
```

In the data dictionary

```
<field number="5017" name="QuikTradeTimeGMT" type="UTCTIMESTAMP"/>
```

So it seems that -3:00:00 is invalid for UTCTIMESTAMP. 
But the time offset can be negative.

Comment: Looks like a bug of the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTC timestamp, read by Quickfix, is in the format of **YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS**. I belive the date data part is missing in your tag value and hence Quickfix is groaning. Check where the Execution Report is being created and check if the values are being populated properly.

Comment: Hi, this is custom field as you can see and the guys use it to pass time zone offset, which can be negative, but on my client side the quickfix cannot parse it. So I will probaly have to change the dictionary definition to string

Comment: @Captain Comic - Custom field is fine, but you cannot change the format of the datatype. You can imagine the headache if everybody was allowed to define the datatype. Why not add all 0s(00000000) before the offset to make it a compatible UTC timestamp ?

Comment: @Captain Comic - Did this help at all ??

Answer (score 0):

The time zone could be negative, but not the time itself. Normally, time zone should not contain seconds (only hours and minutes).

Consider this format yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssK, e.g. 2011-06-30T12:13:11-03:00

Comment: So what is the solution? Do I have to change the dictionary type to what? The message is sent by the sever.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar to quickfix engine, just pointed to the problem. May be this will help you to find a workaround.